# Two complicated limits: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{\sin(cx)}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} x(a^{\frac1x}-1)$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to solve these 2 limits ( without using L'Hospital's Rule) , but I can't figure out how to go about them:

Let $a \neq b$, $c \neq 0$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{\sin(cx)}$$

Also, let $a>0$, $a \neq 1$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x(a^{\frac1x}-1)$$

I don't necessarily need the result, more like understanding the process.

Comment: @science I'm sorry, but that's a bit complicated for this course, as we haven't yet studied Taylor series expansions (although I have). So we should be able to compute these things without stuff like that, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x$, $e^{ax} = 1+ax +O(x^2)$, $e^{bx} = 1+bx+O(x^2)$,  and $\sin cx = cx+O(x^3)$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{\sin cx} & = \frac{\left(1+ax\right)-\left(1+bx\right)+O(x^2)}{cx+O(x^3)} \\\\
& = \frac{(a-b)+O(x)}{c+O(x^2)} \\\\
&= \frac{a-b}{c} \left(1+O(x)\right)
\end{align}$$

which goes to $\frac{a-b}{c}$ as $x \to 0$.

---

For the second limit, we analyze the right-side limit only.

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\left(a^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right) & = \lim_{x \to 0^+} xa^{\frac{1}{x}}-\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \\\\
& = \lim_{x \to 0^+} xa^{\frac{1}{x}} \\\\
& = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\log \left(xa^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)} \\\\
& = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\log (x)+\frac{1}{x}\log(a)} \\\\
& = \begin{cases}\infty&,a>1\\\\0&,0 < a \le  1 \end{cases}
\end{align}$$

This last equality is justified since heuristically, $x^{-1} \to \infty$ faster than $\log x \to -\infty$.

The case for the left-side limit is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: Break it into $2$ parts:$$\dfrac{1}{c}\cdot \dfrac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x}\cdot \dfrac{cx}{\sin(cx)}$$

Comment: I got to that part, but I don't know what to do with the (e^ax-e^bx)/x term.

Comment: It seems to end up being a-b, but I have to solve this without L'Hospital's. No idea where to go from here.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Replace it by $e^{bx}\dfrac{e^{(a-b)x}-1}x$. Remember that $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}x=1$.

Comment: (Also, anything of the form $\dfrac{e^{Tx}-1}x$ can be rewritten as $T\dfrac{e^{Tx}-1}{Tx}$, so $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{Tx}-1}x=T$ for all $T$.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw Thanks man! I had not realized that. I could finish it it now.

Answer (score 1):

In short: factor the smaller exponential out. Use l'Hopital's rule on what remains.

One iteration will do: exponentials stay, and $sin(cx)$ will become $c\cos (cx)$, which goes to $1$ instead.

Comment: The thing is I must prove these without l'Hospital's.

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem the limit does not exist for both cases $0<a<1 $ and $a>1$ since

> 1) case $0<a<1$ $$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} x(a^{1/x}-1) = 0,\quad \lim_{x\to 0^-} x(a^{1/x}-1) = -\infty $$
>
> 2) case $ a>1$ $$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} x(a^{1/x}-1) = \infty,\quad \lim_{x\to 0^-} x(a^{1/x}-1) = 0. $$

Now try to study these cases.

**Note:** I believe you studied the notion of left limit ($\lim_{x\to 0^-}$) and right limit ($\lim_{x\to 0^+}$).

Comment: @Dr.MV: It is his job to find out. We already put him on the track but if he still needs more help he can ask for it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Dr.MV: In fact I drove his attention to a very important point which I do not think he was aware about it which the idea of the left and right limits which is the essence of this answer. Don't you agree?